# Branching and (re-)joining value pairs in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to create a stream that

1. splits values and processes each partial on a separate stream
2. each stream will transform data, I have no control over the applied transformation
3. (re-)joins the partial values with their corresponding counter part

The reason I want to do this is to ensure the integrity of the value. Or at least for some part of it.

Because each stream could have some async operations they do not appear in order when joining the streams. Using some sort of `concat()` also doesn't work because it would block all incoming values. Processing should be done in parallel.

To illustrate:

```
                            o
                            |
                            | [{a1,b1}, {a2,b2}, ...]
                            |
                            +
                           / \
                   {a<x>} /   \ {b<x>}
                         /     \
                        |       |
                        |       + async(b<x>) -> b'<x>
                        |       |
                        \       /
                         \     /
                          \   /
                           \ /
                            + join(a<x>, b'<x>)
                            |
                            | [{a1,b'1}, {a2,b'2}, ...]
                            |
                       (subscribe)
```

I know this can be done via a `result selector` function. E.g.

```
input$.mergeMap(
  ({a, b}) => Rx.Observable.of(b).let(async), 
  ({a}, processedB) => ({a, b:processedB})
);
```

But, (a) this will result in `async` to always be setup/tear down for each value. I would like the partial stream to only be initialized once. Also, (b) this only works with one asynchronously stream.

I also tried to use `window*`, but couldn't figure out how to rejoin values again. Also tried to use `goupBy` with no luck.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my current attempt. It has the mentioned issue (a). `Init...` and `Completed...` should only be logged once.

```js
const doSomethignAsync = data$ => {
  console.log('Init...') // Should happen once.
  return data$
    .mergeMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val.data).delay(val.delay))
    .finally(() => console.log('Completed...')); // Should never happen
};

const input$ = new Rx.Subject();
const out$ = input$
  .mergeMap(
    ({ a, b }) => Rx.Observable.of(b).let(doSomethignAsync),
    ({ a }, asyncResult ) => ({ a, b:asyncResult })
  )
  
  .subscribe(({a, b}) => {
    if (a === b) { 
      console.log(`Re-joined [${a}, ${b}] correctly.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Joined [${a}, ${b}]...`); // Should never happen
    }
  });


input$.next({ a: 1, b: { data: 1, delay: 2000 } });
input$.next({ a: 2, b: { data: 2, delay: 1000 } });
input$.next({ a: 3, b: { data: 3, delay: 3000 } });
input$.next({ a: 4, b: { data: 4, delay: 0 } });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess you can use `pairwise()` and then `merge()` the two streams but I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish so I can give more accurate advise

Comment: I added some more info. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you need to accomplish. It is also unclear what you mean by parallel--it means different things to different people in different contexts. e.g. what is the buffering strategy when you're still waiting on a matching "a" or "b"? Do you just do the pair concurrently, but not multiple of each pair concurrently? Do you need to worry about errors? Unbounded buffers? (e.g. what if each b takes 1 minutes but the incoming rate is 1000 per second)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make any sense. I guess what I am trying to accomplish is very similar to a server, where `a` and `b` is a `res`/`req` pair (like in express). So yes, I want to process the pairs concurrently and have concurrent pairs. I would like to catch errors and handle backpressure, but wanted to start with the parallel processing first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather complex problem to solve and exactly how you do it will depend on very specific details to your use case that weren't included.

That said, here's *one possible way* that makes a bunch of assumptions. It's made to be somewhat generic, like a custom operator to be used with `let`.

(side note: I named it "collate" but this is a bad and highly misleading name for this, but whatevs no time to name things...)

```
const collate = (...segments) => source$ =>
  source$
    .mergeMap((obj, index) => {
      return segments.map(({ key, work }) => {
        const input = obj[key];
        const output$ = work(input);

        return Observable.from(output$).map(output => ({
          index,
          result: { [key]: output }
        }))
      })
    })
    .mergeAll()
    .groupBy(
      obj => obj.index,
      obj => obj.result,
      group$ => group$.skip(segments.length - 1)
    )
    .mergeMap(group$ =>
      group$.reduce(
        (obj, result) => Object.assign(obj, result),
        {}
      )
    );
```

And here's a usage example:

```
const result$ = input$.let(
  collate({
    key: 'a',
    work: a => {
      // do stuff with "a"
      return Observable.of(a).map(d => d + '-processed-A');
    }
  }, {
    key: 'b',
    work: b => {
      // do stuff with "b"
      return Observable.of(b).map(d => d + '-processed-B');
    }
  })
);
```

Given input `{ a: '1', b: '1 }` it would output `{ a: '1-processed-A', b: '1-processed-B' }` and so on, grouped correctly while doing as much concurrently as possible--the only buffering it does is to match all the segments together for a particular input.

Here's a running demo https://jsbin.com/yuruvar/edit?js,output

---

#### Breakdown

There's probably more clear/simpler ways to doing this, especially if you can hardcode some things instead of making them generic. But let's breakdown what I did.

```
const collate = (...segments) => source$ =>
  source$
    // for every input obj we use the index as an ID
    // (which is provided by Rx as autoincrementing)
    .mergeMap((obj, index) => {
      // segments is the configuration of how we should
      // chunk our data into concurrent processing channels.
      // So we're returning an array, which mergeMap will consume
      // as if it were an Observable, or we could have used
      // Observable.from(arr) to be even more clear
      return segments.map(({ key, work }) => {
        const input = obj[key];
        // the `work` function is expected to return
        // something Observable-like
        const output$ = work(input);

        return Observable.from(output$).map(output => ({
          // Placing the index we closed over lets us later
          // stitch each segment back to together
          index,
          result: { [key]: output }
        }))
      })
    })
    // I had returned Array<Observable> in mergeMap
    // so we need to flatten one more level. This is
    // rather confusing...prolly clearer ways but #YOLO
    .mergeAll()
    // now we have a stream of all results for each segment
    // in no guaranteed order so we need to group them together
    .groupBy(
      obj => obj.index,
      obj => obj.result,
      // this is tough to explain. this is used as a notifier
      // to say when to complete() the group$, we want complete() it
      // after we've received every segment for that group, so in the
      // notifier we skip all except the last one we expect
      // but remember this doesn't skip the elements downstream!
      // only as part of the durationSelector notifier
      group$ => group$.skip(segments.length - 1)
    )
    .mergeMap(group$ =>
      // merge every segment object that comes back into one object
      // so it has the same shape as it came in, but which the results
      group$.reduce(
        (obj, result) => Object.assign(obj, result),
        {}
      )
    );
```

---

I didn't think or worry about how error handling/propagation might work because that's highly dependant on your usecase. If you have no control over the processing of each segment, then also including some sort of timeout and `.take(1)` would be advised otherwise you may leak subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am still looking at the solution to understand everything. It has some nice patterns in it wo work with `Observable`s that I never could came up with! :-)